# Formatting Php Form Variable

Tags: php, forms, email

A user fills out a form which is sent to my email via the variables their data is read into.

I want to have headers above each users entry, and have these appear **bold** in the email.

The email should read:

> **OCCUPATION:**
>
> *Data the user entered.*

I have tried

`$Occupationheader = "<strong>"."OCCUPATION"."</strong>"."\n\n" ;`

and

`$Occupationheader = "<strong>OCCUPATION:<strong>\n\n";`

The data is sent to the email, as follows: (this works, but want to format the headings in bold).

`mail( "myemailaddress", "subjectmatter",
  $Occupationheader.$Occupation);`

Any ideas?

Thanks guys.

Comment: You don't say what issue you're actually having. But I'm going to guess that you're not sending out a HTML email , just a text one?

Comment: try using <b></b> instead of <strong></strong>,as this is the tag that is used by JavaScript editors to Bold the content while composing an email

Comment: Show us your full code.

Comment: @Shiva I beg to differ on the `<strong>` part being used by JS. That is a valid HTML tag.

Comment: Are these present in your code? `$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";`. If not, insert those and try it again. Remember to insert it in their proper place, keeping in mind of the concatenated header (`$headers .=`). That may very well be your problem, without seeing your entire code.

Comment: Thanks Fred, I just noticed this in the manual, I am implementing this as we speak :)

Comment: @Jenny You're welcome. Let me know if it worked for you, so I can make it an (additional) answer, cheers.

Comment: Hi Fred, yes it worked, I did what JohnSmith alluded to: `$mailContent= "<html>
<body>
<strong>OCCUPATION</strong>
<br/><br/>$Occupation<br/><br/>
<strong>Engine Used</strong>
<br/><br/>$whichengine<br/><br/>
<strong>Engine Used (If other):</strong>
<br/><br/>$engineused<br/><br/>
<strong>Improvement?</strong>
<br/><br/>$Improvement<br/><br/>
<strong>IP ADDRESS</strong>
</body>
</html>";
$mailContent.= $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` and I made sure I added the headers..`$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";`

Comment: And made sure the mail section was correct: `mail( "myemailaddress", "email subject matter",
  $mailContent,$headers);`

Comment: @Jenny That's great Jenny, glad to hear the problem was solved, cheers.

Comment: @Fred : ya until recently, they both were kinda same,and it were on the will of browsers on how to display them and both were rendered as Boldface . but in HTML 5 <B> and <STRONG> have specific meaning You might wanna look at the HTML 5 specs <B> 's specification: bit.ly/2em2D <STRONG> 's specification: bit.ly/rpE1kd

Comment: @Shiva Thanks Shiva, I just noticed it now. They're always changing something, nothing is left sacred anymore, LOL!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$mailContent = "<html>
<body>
<strong>HEADER</strong>
<br/>message
</body>
</html>";
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Try being a bit more specific in your answers. All I see is setting some variable that the OP doesn't even mention to some HTML tags containing text that the OP didn't mention either. Try adding a few lines of text explaining about why it's not working and exactly how he should integrate your code into his code. Not to mention that you're not even mentioning the mime-type being sent in the email header.

Comment: Hey guys, what JohnSmith provided worked, but I did not know about the $headers information that was required.. but he probably did not know that I did not know!

Comment: @Jenny even if you're not including `<html>` or `<body>` tags, if you're sending an HTML email, `<strong>` tags will bold the text.

Comment: @Mike Are you sure? I think it depends on what mailbox program you use, because without html tag it should be treat like plain text

Comment: @JohnSmith yes, I am sure. I never include the `<html>` tag in my html emails and they always appear perfectly fine.

Comment: it also depends on headers

Comment: Who`s answer should I accept, I don`t want to offend anybody, clues receive by both JohnSmith and Fred! As an aside, if I wished to get a survey/feedback form (the form I am creating now!) completed for my website university project, could I post a link to it on stackoverflow? Or would you recommend another site for this?

Comment: @JohnSmith nay, it *only* depends on headers. If you send HTML with a plain text header, it will be interpreted as plain text. If you send plain text with an HTML header, it will be interpreted as HTML.

Comment: @JohnSmith and Jenny. I'll definitely give a **+1** here for sure, since it is a correct and viable method.

Answer (score 5):

**NOTE: This is provided as an additional answer.**

Without seeing full source code, am providing my (additional) answer below.

The following, need to be present in your code, in order to send out Emails in HTML format:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

As per the PHP manual on the subject: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure which answer I should accept, yours, or JohnSmith. You both gave me clues? As an aside, if I wished to get a survey/feedback form (the form I am creating now!) completed for my website university project, could I post a link to it on stackoverflow? Or would you recommend another site for this?

Comment: You can post a link only if it is relevant to what you're asking and not just spam. Note that it will be a `nofollow` link, so you're not going to get any SEO link juice from it anyway.

Comment: So If I posted a question asking for feedback on my metasearch engine website, and asking people to fill out the feedback form, would this be considered spam, or irrelevant to stackoverflow?

Comment: It has nothing to do with your question, so I'd say irrelevant. Nothing personal.

Comment: Well, I meant posting a new question, separate to this?

Comment: @Jenny You can accept either one as a correct answer, they're both right. As  for your feedback form Jenny, I would think to just post it as a new question, if there's something you're having trouble with. But as for people to use it here to give feedback, would not be appropriate.

Comment: @Fred I gave JohnSmith the answer, he needs the reputation, but thanks for your help!!

Comment: @Jenny I'm all for it, and you're welcome Jenny. Just glad your problem was resolved.